# Stop WPF TextBox from growing

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have spent two hours researching how to avoid that my WPF TextBox Control grows when a long text has been typed in, but I have not been able to do it, even I have read some answers about it like these ones:

[stopping-wpf-textbox-from-growing-with-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720855/stopping-wpf-textbox-from-growing-with-text)

[wpf-allow-textbox-to-be-resized-but-not-to-grow-on-user-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604952/wpf-allow-textbox-to-be-resized-but-not-to-grow-on-user-input)

[wpf-how-to-stop-textbox-from-autosizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465646/wpf-how-to-stop-textbox-from-autosizing)

My code is the following:

```
<Grid>
      <TextBox Margin="6,6,8,28" Name="textBox1" AcceptsTab="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
      <CheckBox Content="Case sensitive" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,0,0,2" Name="checkBox1" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

One thing that I tried was:

```
MaxWidth={Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=ActualWidth}
```

But it did not work for me.

I also tried to add the following property to the Grid:

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

Or

```
<Border x:Name="b" Grid.Column="1"/>
<TextBox Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=b}" ....... />
```

But it did not work either.

I need my control to grow when the user stretches the window, but not to when a long text is inserted.

Do you have a different answer for this problem that I might try?

**UPDATE!**

I have noticed something very strange: If I stretch manually  the window, the textbox stops growing when a long text is inserted. That's fine. But I need to achieve this without having to stretch the window every time I run the program

Comment: Was a solution found?

Answer (score 0):

Remove TextBox border and put it into ScrollViewer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but have tried your solution and It does not work either, thank you anyway

Comment: Manually change TextBox size to values remembered on resize event (I don't exactly know what you mean by "when the user stretches it") on TextChanged event?

Comment: You could also force TextBox size with defining some grid rows and columns.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "when user stretches the window that contains the TextBox"

Answer (score 0):

Try to do next:

```
<ScrollViewer MaxHeight={Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=ActualWidth} BorderThickness="0">                    
      <TextBox Margin="6,6,8,28" Name="textBox1" AcceptsTab="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>          
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tried it, but I did not work either, It still behaves the same way: I have to stretch the window in order to stop my textbox from growing